# streaming mic and camera in actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, streaming

How to make a real time streaming for MIC (Audio) using actionscript 3?

my question about making live radios.

I can have a VPS to start my project.

Comment: Hi I voted to close because I have no idea what your question is, what you've researched or tried or where you're stuck?

Comment: how to make a real time streaming for audio like radio

Comment: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/icecast-streams.html you probably need to read up on streaming in general, you can probably use Red5 to publish a stream that can be subscribed to by multiple users on the fly (Red5 is an open source alternative to Flash Media Server, which I believe you can use for small amounts of connections <10, or something).  Another thing to look into might be P2P using Adobe Cirrus though I'm not sure how well this works for broadcast type scenarios.

Comment: Great :) I know red5 but it's very intricate... Is p2P free ??

Comment: I believe Adobe Cirrus is still free to use, just google it, it still requires a third party to keep track of open connections and to establish an initial connection I believe but then does P2P communication cutting out the need to go through a server.  I've seen demos of video chat applications but nothing beyond 1 to 1 with media, I've also seen chat-room type setups... looks like multi-cast is an option... read more here http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/Cirrus http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/Cirrus:FAQ

Comment: Good informations, thanks a loooooooot